# Julia does not appear to be using string to perform interpolation

Tags: string, julia, string-interpolation

The official docs state:

> Both concatenation and string interpolation call `string()` to convert objects into string form

However, the following minimum working example seems to demonstrate otherwise:

```
type MyType
    x::Int
end
import Base.string
Base.string(m::MyType) = "world"
m = MyType(4)
println("hello $m")
println("hello " * string(m))
```

The second last line evaluates to `hello MyType(4)` at the REPL, while the last line evaluates (as expected) to `hello world`.

So what am I doing wrong?

(I am still on v0.4 but the official doc versions indicate that shouldn't make any difference.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is perfectly correct:

```
julia> expand(:(println("hello $m")))
:(println((Base.string)("hello ",m)))
```

That is to say, `println("hello $m")` is **equivalent** to `println(string("hello", m))`. By the time the code is compiled or interpreted, they are the same thing.

However, your overload

```
Base.string(m::MyType) = "world"
```

is not the correct way to overload `string`. This method only covers the case with a single argument of type `MyType`. (This is why, incidentally, your code seemed to work for concatenation: that particular example involved calling `string` on a single argument. The results would have been the same if you had written `"$m"`.) The correct way to overload it is

```
Base.show(io::IO, m::MyType) = print(io, "world")
```

which may seem weird at first. The reason this must be overloaded is because `string` delegates to `print` which delegates to `show`.

After updating your minimum working example to

```
type MyType
    x::Int
end
Base.show(io::IO, m::MyType) = print(io, "world")
m = MyType(4)
println("hello $m")
println("hello " * string(m))
```

the result is as expected.

---

As a footnote, note that your example can be more performantly written as

```
println("hello ", m)
```

which avoids the creation of intermediate strings. This illustrates *why* the system is set up so that `string` calls `print` which calls `show`: the IO method is more generic and can print to various forms of IO directly, whereas if it went the other way around, one would have to convert things into strings (requiring temporary allocation and thus poor performance) before sending to IO.

Comment: Great answer! Really well explained. One quick question: I've been caught out by this before (I overloaded `Base.<` instead of overloading `Base.isless`), so I was wondering if you have any tips for knowing which functions to overload? Is there a resource that shows which functions are at the "bottom of the chain"?

Comment: ps I could make this a separate StackOverflow question if the answer is at all long. Let me know and I'll do so...

Comment: Truthfully, I don't know the answer. I don't personally know of such a resource. It would be nice to have though.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for answering. I might post something to julia-users about this.

Comment: Regarding `<` vs. `isless`, it is better to overload `isless`. The resource used to discover this is `@edit 1>3` at the REPL which gets to the code and shows the fallback to `isless`.

Comment: @DanGetz So you are suggesting basically just looking at the source to find out the best fallback method to overload? I agree this makes sense in principle, but to some (myself included) it can also lead to confusion. For example, using your example, `@edit 1>3` allows us to find the line `<(x,y) = isless(x,y)` under the heading `#comparison fallbacks` which seems fairly clear cut. But then I browse down another 10 lines or so and find `sless(x::Real, y::Real) = x<y`. And now I'm not so sure... this seems to imply `isless` is defined in terms of `<` for `Real`, not the other way around...

Comment: @DanGetz And as another example of what I mean, I just tried `@edit 2.3+3.2`, and the source file there seems to suggest that this operation calls a function called `box`. So I tried `Base.box(Float64, 2.3, 3.2)` and Julia got very unhappy at me (it crashed). I guess what I'm trying to say is that for an amateur like myself, looking at the source does not always solve the problem. But if that is the only approach to this situation then of course I can accept that and be grateful for what I have :-)

Comment: @ColinTBowers Agree. But looking at the source is still a good fallback, and with much of Julia written in Julia, because it is supposed to solve the 2-language problem, it is easier. Maybe implementing a way to multiedit all methods of a generic function would help - i.e. open multiple buffers, one for each method, like `@edit` does for a single one.