# Overriding `show` to be for a field of a type

Tags: types, julia

```
type MyCompositeType
  x::Float64
  y::Int
end

z = MyCompositeType(1.0,2)
```

I would like the standard show and display methods in Julia to be overridden to only show/display `z.x`, but overriding `display(x::MyCompositeType)` doesn't do that, and I can't find an introduction to MIME types.

Comment: Does `Base.show(io::IO, a::MyCompositeType) = print(io, string(a.x))` do what you want? More reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066212/julia-does-not-appear-to-be-using-string-to-perform-interpolation)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your type to display exactly like some component, then forward `show` to that other type.

```
julia> type MyType
           obj::Vector{Int}
           other::Float64
       end

julia> Base.show(io::IO, x::MyType) = show(io, x.obj)

julia> Base.show(io::IO, m::MIME"text/plain", x::MyType) = show(io, m, x.obj)

julia> MyType([1, 2, 3], 1.5)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> println(MyType([1, 2, 3], 1.5))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using a module:

```
module m

import Base.show

export MyCompositeType

type MyCompositeType
    x::Float64
    y::Int
end

function show(io::IO, v::MyCompositeType)
    println(io,"The x field is $(v.x)")
end

end
```

then you can do

```
julia> using m

julia> z = MyCompositeType(1.0,2)
The x field is 1.0
```

As pointed out by @ColinTBowers, to do this in the REPL you need to define a new method for `Base.show`:

```
Base.show(io::IO, v::MyCompositeType) = println(io,"The x field is $(v.x)")
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't understand why you need the module. If you just call the method definition with `Base.show...` you get the same effect at the REPL. See my comment on the question. It works for me on v0.5...

Comment: @ColinTBowers You're right -- when I first tried it, I missed the `Base.` prefix to `show()`, and it doesn't work without it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No probs. Feel free to use my comment as a template for the answer. I didn't do an answer myself as I wasn't 100% sure I'd understood the question correctly.

Comment: If I do it like this I just get a text return, but I look the nice array rendering in the REPL and Juno. I want it to do the "nice" rendering on `.x`.